# Google Calendar API (Saving events in MongoDB, Express JS)

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose, google-calendar-api

I can't figure out how to save fetched events from Calendar API. I was able to print out array of events in console. I would require save multiple events at once and have verification if they already exist in database with unique id.

Here's my event.js scheme in express js.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const EventSchema = new Schema({
   id: {
      type: String,
      required: false,
      unique:true
   },
   start: {
      type: String
   },
   end: {
      type: String
   },
   status: {
      type: String
   },
   creator: {
      type: Array
   },
   description: {
      type: String
   }
});

module.exports = Event = mongoose.model('events', EventSchema);
```

Here's my event.js router in express js.

```
    router.post("/google/get", async (req, res, next) => {
   const {
      google
   } = require('googleapis')
   const {
      addWeeks
   } = require('date-fns')
   const {
      OAuth2
   } = google.auth
   const oAuth2Client = new OAuth2(
      process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
      process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET
   )
   oAuth2Client.setCredentials({
      refresh_token: process.env.GOOGLE_REFRESH_TOKEN,
   })

   const calendar = google.calendar({
      version: 'v3',
      auth: oAuth2Client
   })

   calendar.events.list({
         calendarId: 'MY CALENDAR ID',
         timeMin: new Date().toISOString(),
         timeMax: addWeeks(new Date(), 1).toISOString(),
         singleEvents: true,
         orderBy: 'startTime',
      },
      function (err, response) {
         if (err) {
            console.log("The API returned an error: " + err)
            return
         }
         var events = response.data.items
         events.forEach(function (event) {
            var start = event.start.dateTime || event.start.date
            console.log("%s - %s", start, event.summary)
         })
      }
   )
```

Answer (score 0):

In Mongoose, in order to save something to a database, all you need to do is to instantiate the model that you created. Your event schema exports Event as a model that you can then treat as a regular object. So you would do something along the lines of:

```
let currentEvent = new Event({id, start, end, status, creator, description});
currentEvent.save();
```

Once that is done, it should be stored in your MongoDB. I assume that as the code for this is not visible it is already set up and working. You can just run the above inside of your for loop with some minor tweaks to grab each value correctly and it should sort your issue out!

As for your unique ID and making sure that it doesn't already exist in your database, you can use the same model to find values by checking the id against your database and seeing if it exists. As follows:

```
Event.findById(id, (err, event) => {
    if(event == null) {
        let currentEvent = new Event({id, start, end, status, creator, description});
        currentEvent.save();
    } else {
        alert("Error, this event already exists")
    }
});
```

I believe something like this should work, however I might have it wrong with how to check if the event exists, I can't remember if it returns null or something different, so just console log the value of event and check to see what it returns if there isn't an event that exists with that ID, and just re-run your if statement with that instead.